# Vuejs sidemenu transition not working with position: fixed

Tags: vue.js, position, css-transitions

I have a sidebar component I would like to animate in and out with a transition. I am using transform translateX (see CSS below).

However, the menu does not animate in properly. It works fine when I get rid of the `position: fixed` css property on the component, however, that leaves it not looking like much of a sidemenu (it is not properly positioned on the screen). With position fixed, it works except that the background color and position of the sidemenu div (and elements within it) aren't finalized until after the animation is over.

So it looks gross. I've looked all over and found similar issues on here, but nothing that led me to a solution other than to use other peoples' pre-built components. (I would like to avoid doing that.)

Here is my html (from parent component) in webpack's vue-loader:-

```
<transition name="slide">
            <app-menu   v-if="menuToggled" 
                        :untoggle="toggleSidebar">
            </app-menu> 
        </transition>
```

Here is the sidemenu's CSS for the div:

```
.menu {
        position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background-color: black; 
        padding: 10px;
        margin-right: 40px;
        text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks! This is my first StackOverflow question. I hope I am not wasting anyone's time here. I very much appreciate constructive guidance of any form.

Comment: Could you post the CSS of the animation, perhaps even the entire component? Something like Github gist would be fine, that would make it a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks ... I will work on this but I am also a Github newbie. I will check in once I do this or solve the problem.

Comment: Here is the entire component in a GitHub gist: https://gist.github.com/robertjoellewis/dfa66f149b8a3bfb5c9d112330ea1564

Comment: Keep in mind the actual transition tag is in the parent component (as you can see in my original post) ... I commented out a place in the git gist where I had the transition tag within the child component previously.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out just now. It was a div placement issue. I was under the impression the "single element" that vue components' template html needs to be wrapped in had to be a div. I didn't know you could wrap anything in whatever tag you wanted. When I made that outside element the transition itself, then everything worked perfectly! Very happy man right now.